# VS Code Insiders error Unhandled rejection: Error spawn C:\...\docker ENOENT repeats infinitely

Tags: docker, visual-studio-code

I'm using VS Code Insiders to connect remotely (via SSH) to various machines back at home through a VPN I have set up. I'm getting the following error repeating over and over again (it seems to be infinitely repeating)

```
Unhandled rejection: Error: spawn C:\Users\styga\AppData\Local\Programs\Microsoft VS Code Insiders\docker ENOENT
    at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (internal/child_process.js:267:19)
    at onErrorNT (internal/child_process.js:469:16)
    at processTicksAndRejections (internal/process/task_queues.js:84:21)
```

It looks like it has something to do with Docker - I only use Docker on one machine, and I get the same errors when I try to connect to that machine, as I do when I connect to all of the others.

Other than the repeating error - the remote connection seems to work OK.